# How do I change my display name in a Zoom webinar with no participant list displayed?

Tags: zoom-meeting

The only way that I can find to change my Zoom display name through the (Windows) desktop app is to go to the participants list. But at Zoom webinars (as opposed to meetings), the participant list is often (or always?) hidden. How can I change my display name in this situation? Although other participants cannot see my display name, the organizers can, and I believe that the other participants might be able to see my display name if I ask a question.

Comment: Don't the instructions in Zoom website work? https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201363203-Customizing-your-profile

Comment: @Peregrino69 Is there a way to do it through the desktop app? I cannot access the web portal, and also I'm not sure if updating my profile through the web portal would change my name for a meeting in progress in the desktop app.

Comment: You just specified webinars, now you're specifying meetings... the page I linked says _"Display Name: This is the name that appears on your profile across the Zoom platform, such as the default name when joining a meeting or webinar"_. I have absolutely no idea whether or not this would affect an ongoing meeting or webinar (I honestly don't see why - and I'm of the generation who used to change nick to "_AFK" in IRC). I simply googled `how to change zoom webinar username`.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Sorry, I meant "webinar" not "meeting" in my comment above. But the point is that I want to do in through the desktop app, not the web portal, and I don't see any way to do so when there is no participant list displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it is impossible to change the display name in another way.

The Windows application redirects to its web version whenever you want to modify your profile. This is common among many applications to save development time.

I don't know what's stopping you from accessing the website, but that's the real problem to solve in this situation.